# Как опубликовать несколько приложений ASP.NET Core на одном сервере Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, nginx, asp.net-core

Сервер: Ubuntu 18 + nginx + apache
Установлен dotnet для Ubuntu

Создал /etc/nginx/sites-available/domen1.conf:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   domen1 www.domen1;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Создал и запустил сервис /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-ASP-NET-core-

```
myApp1.service:
[Unit]
Description=myApp1 .NET Core Web API App running on Ubuntu
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/www/ASP.NET.core/myApp1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/www/ASP.NET.core/myApp1/myApp1.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-ASP-NET-core-myApp1
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Все работает.

Но когда я хочу добавить еще один сайт на ASP.NET Core:

Создал /etc/nginx/sites-available/domen2.conf:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   domen2 www.domen2;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5010;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Создал и запустил сервис /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-ASP-NET-core-

```
myApp2.service:
[Unit]
Description=myApp2 .NET Core Web API App running on Ubuntu
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/www/ASP.NET.core/myApp2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/www/ASP.NET.core/myApp2/myApp2.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-ASP-NET-core-myApp2
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Второй сайт не работает. Я понимаю, что надо дать какую-то команду на прослушивание порта 5010 - как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on

Answer (score 2):

#### Вариант настройки в коде:

Привязать приложение к порту можно в `Program.cs`:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5010);
        });
```

#### Вариант настройки в конфиге (.Net Core 2.1):

Либо можно задать конфигурацию в файле `appsettings.json`, добавив секцию `"Kestrel"`:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:5010"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Есть [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#endpoint-configuration), где можно подробнее изучить настройки сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, пошло!

Comment: Извините за наглость: как сделать тоже через appsetting.json?

Comment: @АлександрИсаев Здесь нет ничего наглого ;) Обновил ответ.

Comment: @АлександрИсаев если вам этот ответ помог, то отблагодарите человека, отметьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: В этом случае я могу не использовать в Program.cs? : .UseKestrel(options => { options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5010); })

Comment: @АлександрИсаев Да, если вы вызываете `CreateDefaultBuilder()`, то можно вообще не вызывать `UseKestrel`.